# Extracting a table field with CSV data

Tags: sql-server

I'm looking into ways to extract data from a particular field in a table. The field has CSV data, and I'd like to put them all in a temp table as individual entries. For example,

```
Create Table #temp (CsvData Varchar(500))
Insert Into #temp Values ('1,2,3,4'), ('3,6,7,9'), ('a,b,c,d'), ('d,f,g,h')
```

How can I extract the data from this CsvData column into another temp table? Ideally I'd like to get unique values, but at this point I'm willing to clean up the data after I get them all.

Comment: Make an effort. Just search the internet for "sql server split string".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example:

```
    Create Table #temp (CsvData Varchar(500));
    Create Table #temp2 (OneValue Varchar(500));
    Insert Into #temp Values
    ('1,2,3,4'), ('3,6,7,9'), ('a,b,c,d'), ('d,f,g,h');
    DECLARE @s VarChar(Max) = '';
    SELECT @s = @s + Replace('INSERT INTO #temp2
    VALUES('''+CsvData+''')',',','''),(''') FROM #temp;
    PRINT @s;
    EXEC (@s);
    SELECT * FROM #temp2;
    DROP TABLE #temp;
    DROP TABLE #temp2;
```